# React placeholder in input elelemnts flowing out on safari

Tags: reactjs, safari

I am doing my new Web-Dev Portfolio in React.
I am facing the problem that I my Contact form the placeholder for the input elements staying inside the input elements how they should be, at least at the Chrome and Firefox Browser. However in Safari they dont do that. the staying at the upper left beginning at the body of the Page. Can tell me somebody how to fix that.

The complete Project is on Github: https://github.com/axmmxa/portfolio-website2-

```
return (
   <>
        <div className='contact-logo spacer-tall  content-left'>
            <img src={Contactlogo}></img>
        </div>

        <div id='contact' className='contact content-left '>
            <h1>Let's talk</h1>

            <form className='contact-form' onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
                <input type='text' name='Name' value={name} onChange={handleNameChange} id='' placeholder='Name'></input>
                <input type='email'name='email' value={email} onChange={handleEmailChange} id=''  placeholder='Email'></input>
                <textarea type='text' name='' value={text}  placeholder='Message' onChange={handleTextChange} cols={5} rows={6}></textarea>
                <button type='submit' >SEND MSG <img src={arrow}></img></button>
            </form>

        
        </div>
   </>
  )
```

Comment: I have tried to replicate the issue in safari browser, I couldn't. Code looks good to me. Can you share more info.